# http responses not being intercepted while in headless mode on chrome

Tags: .net, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless, selenium4

This code works fine while using non headless mode on chrome.

I initiated an instance of INetwork

```
_networkInterceptor = _driver.Manage().Network;
```

setup a network response handler and listening for a specific path once the path is found it basically logs the information and adds the response to a list of responses and start monitoring for the responses.

```
if (interceptedResponse.StatusCode != 200 || !interceptedResponse.Url.Contains(path)) return false;
_logger.LogInformation($"Network interceptor intercepted the response with path - {path}:" +
                  $"\nStatus: {interceptedResponse.StatusCode.ToString()}" +
                  $"\nURL: {interceptedResponse.Url.ToString()}" +
                  $"\nBody: {interceptedResponse.Body}");
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(interceptedResponse.Body);
_responses.Add(path,response);


_networkInterceptor.AddResponseHandler(responseHandler);
_networkInterceptor.StartMonitoring().Wait();
```

If i use the chrome argument --headless the above code does not output the results as while using non headless mode.

I tried to setup remote debugging by using the below arguments

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0");
```

Am i missing any arguments to enable devtools while using chrome in headless mode or such a feature is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `--headless`, use `--headless=chrome`.

Regular headless mode in Chrome has restrictions, but the Chromium developers recently added a **2nd** headless mode that functions the same way as normal Chrome.

There's more info on that here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36

In summary, use **`--headless=chrome`**

(The OLD way was: `--headless`)

---

**January 2023 UPDATE:**

Starting with Chrome 109, the Chromium team renamed the option to `--headless=new`. See https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/e9c516118e2e1923757ecb13e6d9fff36775d1f4 for details.

Comment: NOTE: In January 2023, Chrome 109 renamed the option to `--headless=new`